# Update path for Wordpress script-loader.php

Tags: php, wordpress, scripting

I'm working on a Wordpress site that is showing some console errors. It is not finding the files for a few scripts that are being loaded from script-loader.php, which is a Wordpress core file.
The issue is that the Wordpress environment for this site contains all the Wordpress core directories and files inside a directory called WP. Since Wordpress is not considering that, it is not able to find the resources since the path is incorrect.
`script-loader.php` contains this line of code `$scripts->add( 'editor', "/wp-admin/js/editor$suffix.js", array( 'utils', 'jquery' ), false, 1 );` if I include `/wp/` before `wp-admin` everything works as intended, but of course, I should not modify a core file.
How can I update the path without modifying a core file so Wordpress will find these files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you gone over the documentation for [Having WordPress in a subdirectory](https://wordpress.org/support/article/giving-wordpress-its-own-directory/)? If you installed WordPress under the standard "root path" method, you may need to change your `.htaccess` file, note specifically the `RewriteBase` and second `RewriteRule`:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ – [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wp/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

There are plenty of other resources on running WordPress from a subdirectory, but the basics generally boil down to:

- Make sure your rewrite rules accommodate the directory you're using
- Make sure your `siteurl` and `homeurl` options are set properly